# Call to undefined method sfApplyApplyForm::isCaptchaEnabled

Tags: php, symfony1, hosting

I’m getting a funny error after I deploy a fully working symfony project to my web host (hostgator).  Everything works fine on my localhost.

Here’s the error:

500 | Internal Server Error | sfException
Call to undefined method sfApplyApplyForm::isCaptchaEnabled.

Here’s what I’m using:

- Symfony 1.4
- Doctrine 2.0
- sfForkedDoctrineApplyPlugin - for
  registering new users with:
- sfDoctrineGuardPlugin - for
  authentication

I get the error when I click the “Register” link.

Obviously, the form is Captcha enabled.  I’ve tried turning it off in config/app settings with no change in error.  I’ve also confirmed that my public and private keys are correct and registered... I’ve even updated them with no change in error msg.

A search on Google brings up nothing helpful.

Any ideas about where to begin troubleshooting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To correct this problem I just copied the isCaptiaEnabled() method from the plugin to the model class where I embedded the plugin form.  I believe I had to also copy a couple of other methods over as well.  But as soon as I did that, the errors never came back.